# Postgresql fulltext search for Czech language (no default language config)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to setup fulltext search for Czech language. I am little bit confused, because I see some `cs_cz.affix` and `cs_cz.dict` files inside `tsearch_data` folder, but there is no Czech language configuration (it's probably not shipped with Postgres).

So should I create one? Which dics do I have to create/config? Is there some support for Czech language at all?
Should I use all possible dicts? (`Synonym Dictionary, Thesaurus Dictionary, Ispell Dictionary, Snowball Dictionary`)

I am able to create Czech configuration for `ispell` dict and it works fine, bud I am not sure if it's enough (just ispell configuration).

Thanks a lot I tried to read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html but I am little bit confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never tried it, but you should be able to create a Czech Snowball stemmer as long as you are ready to compile PostgreSQL from source.

There is an explanation in [`src/backend/snowball/README`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/snowball/README):

> The files under `src/backend/snowball/libstemmer/` and
>   `src/include/snowball/libstemmer/` are taken directly from their libstemmer_c
>   distribution, with only some minor adjustments of file inclusions.  Note
>   that most of these files are in fact derived files, not master source.
>   The master sources are in the Snowball language, and are available along
>   with the Snowball-to-C compiler from the Snowball project.  We choose to
>   include the derived files in the PostgreSQL distribution because most
>   installations will not have the Snowball compiler available.
>
> To update the PostgreSQL sources from a new Snowball `libstemmer_c`
>   distribution:
>
> 1. Copy the `*.c` files in `libstemmer_c/src_c/` to `src/backend/snowball/libstemmer`
>      with replacement of `"../runtime/header.h"` by `"header.h"`, for example
>
>    ```sh
>    for f in libstemmer_c/src_c/*.c
>    do
>        sed 's|\.\./runtime/header\.h|header.h|' $f >libstemmer/`basename $f`
>    done
>    ```
>
>    (Alternatively, if you rebuild the stemmer files from the master Snowball
>      sources, just omit `"-r ../runtime"` from the Snowball compiler switches.)
> 2. Copy the `*.c` files in `libstemmer_c/runtime/` to
>      `src/backend/snowball/libstemmer`, and edit them to remove direct inclusions
>      of system headers such as `<stdio.h>` – they should only include `"header.h"`.
>      (This removal avoids portability problems on some platforms where `<stdio.h>`
>      is sensitive to largefile compilation options.)
> 3. Copy the `*.h` files in `libstemmer_c/src_c/` and `libstemmer_c/runtime/`
>      to `src/include/snowball/libstemmer`.  At this writing the header files
>      do not require any changes.
> 4. Check whether any stemmer modules have been added or removed.  If so, edit
>      the `OBJS` list in `Makefile`, the list of `#include`'s in `dict_snowball.c`, and the
>      `stemmer_modules[]` table in `dict_snowball.c`.
> 5. The various stopword files in `stopwords/` must be downloaded
>      individually from pages on the [snowball.tartarus.org](http://snowballstem.org/) website.
>      Be careful that these files must be stored in UTF-8 encoding.

Now there is a Czech Snowball stemmer available [here](http://snowballstem.org/otherapps/oregan/), it was contributed to the project. There is no stop word dictionary available, but I am sure you can either find one or create one yourself.

The real work would be to install Snowball and use the Snowball-to-C compiler to create the C and header files to add to the PostgreSQL source.
These files should then remain stable, so it shouldn't be difficult to upgrade to a new PostgreSQL version.

If you are willing to do the work, but don't want to patch PostgreSQL and build it from source every time, you could also consider submitting a patch to PostgreSQL. As long as the stemmer works fine, I don't expect that you will much resistance there (but the patch submission process is still tedious).

Comment: I followed the guidelines and made this commit (aka patch): [postgres_snowball_czech](https://github.com/datlowe/postgres_snowball_czech/commit/4363325f719a463fce04c04cbcdcc7e625cdbca5) a derived `docker` image can be found here: https://github.com/datlowe/postgres-pgq-tsearch-czech